# JPA/Hibernate select element not in collection

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

If I have two entity classes, `Group` and `Person`, where there is a one-to-many relationship between `Group` and `Person` (that is, a person can belong to at most one group, a group can have many persons), what jpql/hql query can I use to select all `Person`s not in `Group`s?

Something like the reverse of `select p from Group g inner join g.people p`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
select p from Person p where p not in (select pg from Group g inner join g.persons pg)
```

Maybe:

```
select p from Person p where not exists (select 1 from Group g where p member of g.persons)
```

is more efficient?

In any case... comments are welcome as to which is more efficient, but since both of these "work", marking the question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have all persons who are not in a given group g, it should be like

```
from Person p where p.group.id != :gid;
```

and you set gid to the id of the given group.

If you want to have all persons who are in no group at all

```
from Person p where p.group.id is null;
```

If you want to have all persons who are in no group at al, but it is possible the foreign key in Person has a group id which is not null but does not belong to an existing group (for example if the group was deleted without deleting the persons in it and without moving them to a different group)

```
from Person p where not exist (select 1 from Group g where g.id = p.group.id);
```

P. S. My statements are for HQL, but for JPQL it should be more or less the same.

Comment: Problem is the relationship is one-way.  `Person` doesn't have a reference to `Group`, only the other way around.  HQL is fine, though.  Edited question to reflect this.

Comment: There is a 1:n relation from group to person. Then in the database the table person has the group id as foreign key to the group. With the correct mapping this foreign key can be accessed in the person instance - either with a many-to-one relation, then use `p.group.id' as I did in the examples, or directly as a literal, then use sth. like `p.groupId`. If the foreign key is not mapped yet, then I recommend to map it - that is much faster than any `not exists` or `not in` construction.

Comment: Problem is the collection is ordered, so I need a join table to track order index, rather than simply a 'group id' column in `Person`.